# Problema al debuggear odoo12 con pycharm / Process finished with exit code -1073740940

Tags: odoo

Al debuggear odoo12 en el pycharm obtengo el siguiene mensaje

> Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

He probado con varias versiones del pycharm y me pasa lo mismo 4.5.3, 2016 y 2019

Llevo varios dias revisando en internet haciendo las cosas que dicen para resolver esto y no he logrado terminar con el problema.

Answer (score 1):

[image: solucion]

En (panel de control) -> (region)
Hacer lo que dice la foto.